# Why is it happend when appending the response to the div all the data is responsed as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have filtering module for items where I need to append all the items on the menu board. However, I currently experience problem on my response, it shows `[object Object]`. I already searched some of solutions, however, its still responded as `[object Object]`. They answered that I need to convert the data to JSON string, however, it still is not working.

**Output**:
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image: Expected Output]

**Response**:
[image: response]

**Function**:

```
success: function(res)
{
    $('.virtual_list_product_wrapper').html('');
    $('.list_product_wrapper').html('');
    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    //Receiving the result of search here
    var response = res
    var append_list_product;
    var append_list_product_category;
    $.each(response.filter_product_category,function(key,val_product_category){

        append_list_product_category = '<p style="font-weight:bold;">'+val_product_category.pcat_name+'</p>\
            <div class="row">\
            '+
            
                $.each(response.filter_product_table,function(key,val_product_table){
                    if(val_product_category.pcat_name == val_product_table.product_category) {
                        '<div class="col-md-4">\
                                <div class="card shadow">\
                                    <img src="" class="card-img-top">\
                                    <div class="card-body">\
                                        <h5 class="card-title">\
                                                \
                                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">\
                                                    <p>'+val_product_table.product_name+'</p>\
                                                    <p style="color:#e74a3b; font-weight:bold;">₱'+val_product_table.product_price+'</p>\
                                                </div>\
                                        </h5>\
                                        <p class="card-text" style="font-size:12px;">'+val_product_table.pcat_desc+'</p>\
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger form-control shadow onClickAddBag" \
                                        style="font-size:13px;" \
                                        data-attri-prod-name='+val_product_table.product_name+' \
                                        data-attri-prod-price='+val_product_table.product_price+'>Add to bag</a>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>';


                        $('.appended_product_list').append(append_list_product_category);
                        
                    }
                });
            +'\
            </div>\
        ';
       
    });
```

Hope someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: can you show op of `response` which you get from ajax ?

Comment: sure, i will update my post

Comment: please see the the update post

Comment: your response which have shown is `json object` not `array` ? also where is  `filter_product_category` ?

Comment: You can't use string concatenation with `$.each`  that's why there is `[object object]`

Comment: @GhanuBha what is the alternative way to solve the issue for this.

Comment: @Swati I update my post again please take a look thanks

Comment: `append_list_product_category = "Your string";` Then `$.each("", function(){append_list_product_category += "Your next string" });`

Comment: And do no append within $.each. Use append after $.each

Comment: @GhanuBha thank you for your suggestion but the expected i want is not visible to your suggestion

Comment: [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9bz2xr8/2/) check here. I have created fiddle that help you.

Comment: @GhanuBha that make sense your work.. please create your answer below so i can up it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have changed in your code that helps you.

```
$('.virtual_list_product_wrapper').html("");
    $('.list_product_wrapper').html('');
    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    var response ={
        filter_product_category : [
            {
                pcat_name: "ABC", 
                filter_product_table : [
                    {
                        product_category: "ABC",
                        product_name: "Product 1",
                        product_price: "2.55",
                        pcat_desc: "Lorem Ipsum"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };



var append_list_product = "";
   var append_list_product_category = "";

$.each(response.filter_product_category,function(key,val_product_category){


    append_list_product_category += '<p style="font-weight:bold;">'+val_product_category.pcat_name+'</p>';
    append_list_product_category +=    '<div class="row">';
            
    $.each(response.filter_product_table,function(key,val_product_table){
        if(val_product_category.pcat_name == val_product_table.product_category) {
            append_list_product_category +='<div class="col-md-4">'
            append_list_product_category += '<div class="card shadow">';
            append_list_product_category += '<img src="" class="card-img-top">';
            append_list_product_category += '<div class="card-body">'
            append_list_product_category += '<h5 class="card-title">'
            append_list_product_category += '<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">';
            append_list_product_category += '<p>'+val_product_table.product_name+'</p>';
            append_list_product_category += '<p style="color:#e74a3b; font-weight:bold;">₱'+val_product_table.product_price+'</p>';
            append_list_product_category += '</div>';
            append_list_product_category += '</h5>';
            append_list_product_category += '<p class="card-text" style="font-size:12px;">'+val_product_table.pcat_desc+'</p>';
            append_list_product_category += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger form-control shadow onClickAddBag" style="font-size:13px;"  data-attri-prod-name="'+val_product_table.product_name+'" data-attri-prod-price="'+val_product_table.product_price+'">Add to bag</a>';
            append_list_product_category += '</div>';
            append_list_product_category += '</div>';
            append_list_product_category += '</div>';
        }
    });
    append_list_product_category += '</div>';
});
$('.appended_product_list').html(append_list_product_category);
```

Also get JS Fiddle as follow, to change and check.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ougwxkd2/3/)